# Why is 'Use Strict' causing functions to be undefined

Tags: javascript, use-strict

I have a partial that is loading two scripts. The second script calls a function in the first script... Both scripts use "use strict;" at the top. When the second script calls the function in the first script, I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError *the function name* is not defined".

At first I thought it had to do with the order of the scripts, but after some debugging I found the scripts were executing in the correct order. The partial loads via a jquery async call and is just appended to the current view. Also, I can call the first script's function just fine in chrome's debugger up until the second file gets loaded.

I went kinda crazy and just chopped out everything and it's still happening. Here's what I'm working with...

Script 1

```
"use strict";

var firstScript = function () {
    alert("first");
};
```

Script 2

```
"use strict";

var secondScript = function () {
    alert("second");
};
```

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/../SomeController/SomeAction",
    success: function (content) {
        $("#someDiv").html(content);
    }
});
```

Partial

```
<script src="~/Some/Folder/Js/Script1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Some/Folder/Js/Script2.js"></script>
```

Once the page loads, I open up chrome debugger and doing "firstScript()" or "secondScript()" throws the same error.

BUT, if I take out the `use strict;` on both files they both work. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Is that really the **complete** contents of those script files?

Comment: Are they in the correct order? I.e. do you call `secondScript` before the include?

Comment: I'm using it with asp.net to get the actual content

Comment: @Pointy Yes, I actually copied and pasted that part from my files :|

Comment: @EBrown right now I'm not even calling it in the scripts. I'm just triggering this event to happen that loads the scripts and then just trying to call it from chrome's debugger console. Like, the functions just aren't part of the global list of functions if I use "use script" but I can't find anything about "use script" that would prevent that from happening.

Again, works just fine if I delete "use script" in both files.

Comment: jQuery uses `eval` to execute scripts that it loads, and strict mode prohibits declaring new values within `eval`.

Comment: @Barmer does that include even making new functions? Like `function script1() { alert("test"); }` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Dug a little deeper after reading Barmar's comment. Any  tags included in the partial were being evaluated by [jquery's globalEval](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.globaleval/) function, which of course uses `eval()` My scripts had `"use strict";` and one of the features of `"use strict";` is to prevent `eval()` from affecting the global scope, which is why I was getting undefined functions.

Comment: Who knows, brain typing in auto-pilot most likely :P